# Access denied after installation

Tags: users, installation

I just finished the installation, everything went fine but when I go to view my site I can not login. I cant get to /user

have a look:
www.huf.co.nz

all worked fine on my local before I tried to make live

I have cleared all cookies and cache

Answer (score 1):

Checking your URL, I see that going to http://www.huf.co.nz/user gives a 404 (page not found) from your web server, but http://www.huf.co.nz/?q=/user render's Drupal's login page.  This means that for some reason, "clean URLs" -- i.e., URLs that don't have the "?" in them -- aren't set up right.

It isn't clear what web server you're using from the 404 page.  If you're using Apache, then just look at the README file in the base of the Drupal install, or go to https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/beginners, since looking at your HTML you appear to be using Drupal 7.42.  Apache is the easiest web server to set up, since Drupal ships with a .htaccess file that sets things up for clean URLs.

Drupal 7 also ships with a web.config file for using IIS, if you are serving Drupal from that web server.

If you're using something like nginx, you need to add a bit of configuration in order to get the web server to properly turn your URLs into the format that Drupal needs to see; nginx won't read a .htaccess file.  If you are using nginx, Google "perusio drupal", or go to https://github.com/perusio/drupal-with-nginx.

If you're using anything other than those 3, you'll need to find someone who knows how to translate an Apache type configuration into that web server's configuration.